# My Asp.net mvc actions that return collection generate urls containing system.linq.Enumerable, how to remove them

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

I have an mvc application that basically generates views which are bascially collections but collections of a particular type..so i.e.

```
IEnumerable<IType>
```

Now my urls contain stuff like this

www.site/home/section/param?System.Linq.Enumerable%.....

I want to remove anything after section.

I have tried the routeMap but have been unable to ommit the system.linq etc. Any ideas or help please

Here is my action method

```
public ActionResult Whatever(IEnumerable<IType> whatever)
        {
            return View(whatever);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question above is a very interesting and took me a while and has go back to my previously written mvc app. The answer is simple but not obvious.

And it seems in the current mvc3 even if you pass the object as anonymous type mapping your view to your view model, it always works out the collectiontype and somehow appends that to the url in this case it was appending whole case to the url as

http://www.website.com/param=system.linq.enumerable.where.select..

any way the correct way is to wrap it in a routevaluedictionary

new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = Constants.HOMECONTROLLER, action = Constants.APPLYAPP }));

and if you are passing any stuff from one action to another use this

```
return new RedirectToRouteResult(Constants.DEFAULTROUTE,
                     new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = Constants.HOMECONTROLLER, action = Constants.APPLYAPP }));
```

instead of RedirecttoAction because it seems this results in the url above.

Thanks MattyTommo for the help but its irrelevant in my case but it may be helpful for others. I cannot mark mattytommo's reply as answer at all because it actually misunderstood my request, perhaps my request wasnt correct but also misguided me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass around collections like that in the URL, you shouldn't add them to the `RouteValueDictionary` when you redirect. Just send some basic information that can help you get what you need in the action you are redirecting to.

**Edit:** Based on your code, we can see that your action method takes an `IEnumerable`, so wherever you are calling this action, you're passing it one. You **can't do that**, you'll have to generate your list in the action method. Try something like:

```
public ActionResult Whatever()
{
    List<IType> whatever = new List<IType>();

    //populate your list here, then we can return it

    return View(whatever);
}
```

Comment: I am not passing collections anywhere, this url is generated from mvc itself. I am just displaying a collection in a view. My action return a view by this call 'return View(something)'

Comment: @user182630 You must be passing it in on a redirect somewhere, can you post your action method?

Comment: @user182630 See how your action method takes `IEnumerable` as a parameter? That's your problem. You'll have to generate that in the `Whatever` action method and then return it to the view.

Comment: but my view takes ienumerable<itype>, it shouldnt have anything to do with system.linq.enumerable

Comment: @user182630 That's fine, you can still return that, but you can't pass it to the Action Method. `System.Linq.IEnumerable` is `IEnumerable`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11933/discussion-between-user182630-and-mattytommo)

Comment: @user182630 Sorry I can't chat at the moment I'm at work, but I've added some code for you, check my edited answer :)

Comment: so what do i pass in the view, i cant pass var, cant see your answer with code

Comment: @user182630 public ActionResult Whatever()
{
    List<IType> whatever = new List<IType>();

    //populate your list here, then we can return it

    return View(whatever);
}

Comment: I am not working with concrete objects and it wont work like this for my code, secondly it works fine in another mvc2 application just fine. its mvc3 its like this and even when i try which I have to pass it without a type as in putting it in a var by retreiving from tempdata it still works out as ienumerable, somehow

Comment: @user182630 Hmmm okay. Just put it in `TempData` then, remove it from your call and do `public ActionResult Whatever() { IEnumerable<IType> whatever = TempData["whatever"] as IEnumerable<IType(); return View(whatever); }`